# Selenium, cannot find button to click

Tags: automated-testing, webdriver, selenium2

I got stuck to write the code in WebDriver. I have the code below :

```
<button class="btn" onclick="javascript:return PopulateInvestor('hdnInvestorId', 'txtInvestorName', 'txtInvestorEmail', '', '', '', '', '',false,'hdnInvestorName','hdnInvestorEmail');">Select</button>
```

For this I wrote the following:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;        
jse.executeScript("document.getElement(By.xpath(\"//div[@class='modal-footer']/button[@onclick'return javascript:return PopulateInvestor('hdnInvestorId', 'txtInvestorName', 'txtInvestorEmail', '', '', '', '', '',false,'hdnInvestorName','hdnInvestorEmail');']\").click()");
```

But still it could not identify element and could not click the button.
I can see there is select button present at the end of the code but don't know how to use it. Please advise for this.

Comment: Is it necessary to find and click the element via `JavascriptExecuter`?

Comment: i executed using javascriptExecuter just for check in bcuz it has javascript embedded with the code so i thought of using same for the above code .Please guide me in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn' and contains(@onclick,'PopulateInvestor')]"));
element.click();
```

The driver search for the element on this way

- element has attribute `class` and the value of this is `btn`
- element has attribute `onclick` and the value of this contains the string `PopulateInvestor`

Maybe the first point is not necessary to identify the element, but I do not know the whole HTML code.

Comment: thanx a lot Twaldigas for the solution it worked :)

Comment: @RanjanGupta Glad to hear. Please accept this answer, so every visitor can easily see that this works.

Answer (score 4):

Try this line of code:

Driver.findElement(By.xpath("enter your xpath")).click();

Hope it works out!